# Iterate through a list to get nicknames

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make an email generator using a list of names and their common nicknames. How would I check to see if the first name is in the name list and if it is iterate through a list of nick names for the name.

Code:

```
name_list = ["Aaron", "Abel", "Abiah", "Abijah", "Abiel"]

name = "Aaron"
Aaron = ["Erin", "Ron", "Ronnie"]

i = 0

if name in name_list:
    print("Yes")
    nick_name_length = len(name)
    while nick_name_length >= i:
        print(name[i])
        i += 1
```

I am having difficulty switching between the name variable and the list.

Desired Output:

```
Erin
Ron
Ronnie
```

Comment: what output are you getting? it looks fine at first glance

Comment: your "aaron" variable that is a list of 3 names, do you have this for every name (ie abel, abiah, abijah, etc all have their own lists associated with them?

Comment: @Mitchnoff Yes, I think I need to convert the name string into an actionable list variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create variables based on the name. Instead create a nicknames dictionary.

```
nicknamesbyname = {
    "Aaron": ["Erin", "Ron", "Ronnie"],
    "Steven": ["Stevie", "Steve"]
}
```

To get the nicknames for any given name just do

```
nicknames = nicknamesbyname.get(name, [])
```

If there are no nicknames you get back an empty list.

Note that you could just put all of your names as keys in the `nicknamesbyname` and dispense with the `names` list altogether.

```
nicknamesbyname = {
    "Aaron": ["Erin", "Ron", "Ronnie"],
    "Abel": ["Abe"],
    "Abiah": [], # no nicknames so it's just an empty list
    "Steven": ["Stevie", "Steve"]
}
```

Comment: Would this allow me to see "if name is in nicknames:" then select the nickname list?

Comment: yes. Use `nicknames[name]` to get the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you don't need to have the `i` iterator
Try this:

```
name_list = ["Aaron", "Abel", "Abiah", "Abijah", "Abiel"]

name = "Aaron"
Aaron = ["Erin", "Ron", "Ronnie"]
if name in name_list:
    print("Yes")
    for nickname in Aaron:
        print(nickname)
```

If you wanted to do it your way using `i`, you reference the wrong list:

```
name_list = ["Aaron", "Abel", "Abiah", "Abijah", "Abiel"]
name = "Aaron"
Aaron = ["Erin", "Ron", "Ronnie"]
i = 0
if name in name_list:
    print("Yes")
    nick_name_length = len(Aaron)
    while nick_name_length >= i:
        print(Aaron[i])
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of small changes will make it do what you want:

```py
name_list = ["Aaron", "Abel", "Abiah", "Abijah", "Abiel"]

name = "Aaron"
Aaron = ["Erin", "Ron", "Ronnie"]

i = 0

if name in name_list:
    print("Yes")
    nick_name_length = len(Aaron)  ### 'name' changed to 'Aaron'
    while nick_name_length > i:    ### '>=' changed to '>'
        print(Aaron[i])            ### 'name' changed to 'Aaron'
        i += 1
```

And this is a bit more elegant

```py
name_list = ["Aaron", "Abel", "Abiah", "Abijah", "Abiel"]
name = "Aaron"
Aaron = ["Erin", "Ron", "Ronnie"]

if name in name_list:
    print("Yes")
    for i in range(len(Aaron)): 
        print(Aaron[i])
```

And this is one approach to making it more actionable, storing the nicknames
in a dictionary

```py
name_list = ["Aaron", "Abel", "Abiah", "Abijah", "Abiel"]
nicknames = {"Aaron":["Erin", "Ron", "Ronnie"],
             "Abel":["Abe"]
            }
for name in name_list:
    nicks = nicknames.get(name,[])
    for nick in nicks: 
        print(name, nick)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
nicknames_dict = {
    "Aaron" :["Erin", "Ron", "Ronnie"],
    "Abel": [],
    "Steven" :["Stevie", "Steve"]
}
name_list = ["Aaron", "Abel", "Abiah", "Abijah", "Abiel", "Steven"]

mail_dict = {name: [f'{nickname.lower()}@yourmail.com' 
                for nickname in nicknames_dict.get(name, [])] 
         for name in name_list }
```

and `mail_dict` contains:

```
{'Aaron': ['erin@yourmail.com', 'ron@yourmail.com', 'ronnie@yourmail.com'],
 'Abel': [],
 'Abiah': [],
 'Abijah': [],
 'Abiel': [],
 'Steven': ['stevie@yourmail.com', 'steve@yourmail.com']}
```

`nicknames_dict` is a dictionary that holds <key, value list> pairs where the key is the name and the value list is the list of nicknames **<name, nicknames_list>**.

`list_name` is the list of names whose emails you want to create.

`dict_mail` is the dictionary containing **<name, mail_list>**.